# How to configure Apache Virtual Hosts with SSL SAN

Tags: ssl

I am using a multi-SAN SSL certificate. All the domains use the same document root, Rewrite Rules and other settings.

So, I configured (shortened) :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName domain-a.com
ServerAlias domain-b.com
// usual cert and settings here
</VirtualHost>
```

Which works for domain-a and not for domain-b.

If I set up as :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName domain-a.com   
// usual cert and settings here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName domain-b.com    
// usual cert and settings here
</VirtualHost>
```

it does work. But this seems like an unnecessary hassle as I'm repeating all the cert/settings for each domain (there's a lot of them)

From reading, I'm sure I can't have more than one ServerName and I would assume that the SSL isn't liking the ServerAlias.

But is there a better way to do this ? At the least, is there a way to replicate all the standard cert/rewrite rules (a kind of 'include') so that each VirtualHost is a few lines ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to search for CA which support SAN ([Subject Alternative Names](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-san/)). Then you can request one certificate with many hosts inside.

Let's Encrypt support it too. You may check [this page](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/integration-guide/). It support up to 100 name per certificate.

And you should add

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

before servers definitions.